# JS, вывод хинта над выделенным текстом

Tags: javascript

Получаю выделенный юзером текст: 
https://jsfiddle.net/o7qu9034/
Теперь нужно вывести над текстом хинт.

НО, даже если брать статичный хинт, который будет спрятан до момента срабатывания функции, то я элементарно не могу получить координаты, что бы его навесить чуть выше текста, ибо `txt.offset` - нет такого метода у getSelection, а сам кусок выделенного текста может и не быть засунут в какой либо тег. И в итоге хинт выскочит не там, где нужно.

В общем, как можно навесить хинт над конкретно выделенным текстом?

Comment: можно брать координаты курсора мышки и основываться на них

Comment: @Mit9l, плохой вариант, если текст был выделен "на лету" и сверху вниз. В итоге он перекроет нафиг часть текста и вылезет где-нибудь посередине.

Comment: Может быть, можно [получить координаты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328) выделения и переместить хинт, например, чуть выше этих координат?

Comment: @pocketgulag, вот, то, что нужно, спасибо. Оформите в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе [двух](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964743) [ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328) с EnSO. Дополнительно к получению координат из выделения удаляются начальные символы переноса строки.

```js
function getSelectionCoordsAndText(win) {
    win = win || window;
    var doc = win.document;
    var sel = doc.selection, range, rects, rect;
    var x = 0, y = 0, text = '';
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            while(/^(?:\r|\n)+/.test(range.text)){
                range.moveStart('character', 1);
            }          
            text = range.text;
            if(text != ''){
                range.select();
                range.collapse(true);
                x = range.boundingLeft;
                y = range.boundingTop;
            }
        }
    } else if (win.getSelection) {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        var fNode = sel.focusNode;
        var fOffset = sel.focusOffset;
        // Detect if selection is backwards
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(fNode, fOffset);
        var backwards = range.collapsed;
        range.detach();
        while(/^(?:\r|\n)+/.test(sel.toString())){
            if(backwards){
                sel.modify('extend', 'forward', 'character');
            } else {
                sel.collapse(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
                sel.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
                sel.extend(fNode, fOffset);
            }
        }
        text = sel.toString();
        if (text != '' && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                range.collapse(true);
                rects = range.getClientRects();
                if (rects.length > 0) {
                    rect = rects[0];
                    x = rect.left;
                    y = rect.top;
                }
            }
            // Fall back to inserting a temporary element
            if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
                var span = doc.createElement("span");
                if (span.getClientRects) {
                    // Ensure span has dimensions and position by
                    // adding a zero-width space character
                    span.appendChild( doc.createTextNode("\u200b") );
                    range.insertNode(span);
                    rect = span.getClientRects()[0];
                    x = rect.left;
                    y = rect.top;
                    var spanParent = span.parentNode;
                    spanParent.removeChild(span);

                    // Glue any broken text nodes back together
                    spanParent.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y, text: text };
}
$(document).on('mouseup click', function(){
    var selData = getSelectionCoordsAndText();
    if(selData.text != ''){
        $('#hint').show();
        var xOffset = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        var yOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        $('#hint').css({left: selData.x+xOffset, top: selData.y+yOffset-10});
    } else {
        $('#hint').hide();
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hint').on('selectstart', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
<p><br><br><br><br>Этот текст можно выделять. И этот текст тоже</p>
<p><br><br><br>Этот текст можно выделять. И этот текст тоже</p>
<p>Этот текст можно выделять. И этот текст тоже</p>
<p>Этот текст можно выделять. И этот текст тоже</p>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="hint" style="position:absolute; display:none; background-color:aqua; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;">Hint</div>
```

Comment: теперь вылезла новая проблема: координаты по высоте считаются от начала страницы, а не видимой области, и хинт в случае скроллинга хинт вешается намного выше, чем нужно. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lk2r8zL7/

Comment: @ВиталийRS обновил ответ.